# How to get NGINX to reverse proxy and app

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx reverse proxy in front of an app (Keycloak).
I need to reference the app with a prefix (so I can have multiple copies). Of course the app won't recognise the prefix (sandpit) so this must be stripped off before hitting the app.

So

```
 location /sandpit/
          {
             proxy_pass https://10.8.10.38:8443/;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
}
```

This works fine, /sandpit/ is stripped off the url and I can get to the initial page, provided that page doesn't call anything else. 
When it does, it uses the base path, not /sandpit/base_path, there is no route through nginx for / and I get a 404.
So keycloak will send a redirect for https://keycloak.local:8443/auth and I need the browser to request https://keycloak.local:8443/sandpit/auth

Everything I have read says I should use

```
proxy_redirect https://keycloak.local:8443/auth/ /sandpit/auth/;
```

but this directive, and any other permutation I've tried, is ignored and the browser shows https://keycloak.local:8443/auth and a 404.

How do I get NGINX to rewrite on the way back to the browser and reverse what it does on the way in?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try `proxy_redirect / /sandpit/;`?

Comment: Thanks Ivan, if I add that and go to https://keycloak.local:8443/sandpit/ the browser returns https://keycloak.local:8443/auth/ and I get a 404.
Thinking about it, I'm not sure this concept works at all, as any page links on the app would surely have the wrong url on them too, unless I can send the correct path to the app in the first place.

Comment: Can you post full set of HTTP response headers when you request https://keycloak.local:8443/sandpit/ ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a way to export the responses - so this is what I see in the console. (And this doesn't seem to format very well no matter what I do). Hopefully you can get what you need from it.


Navigated to https://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/sandpit/. 

GET https://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/sandpit/.    200

Navigated to https://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/auth/

GEThttps://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/auth/.        404 

GEThttps://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/favicon.ico 404

Comment: Use some external service, for example https://pastebin.com
I want to see something like this: https://pastebin.com/Ct4rm0pR

Comment: Can you post output from `curl -I https://qlik.dw.test.dbs:8443/sandpit/`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/JJaLxNM8

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MzzR4cyt

Comment: You got an HTTP 200 code, so `proxy_redirect` directive is useless here - it works only for HTTP 3xx redirects. You can try [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) to rewrite links inside your response body.

Comment: Thanks I did wonder whether it was 300 style only (made sense) but the docs simply say it will rewrite a response. All examples are for simple web sites with 301 style redirects. In my case I'm fronting a bought in app that I can't modify so I suspect what I'm trying to do is not possible (the app will generate urls that NGINX can't route) but I'll have a lot at the sub_module.